# Accessing class instantiated outside slim from class instantiated inside slim?

Tags: php, oop, slim

```
require ('dataclass.php');
$db = new DataClass();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->group('/api/v1', function () use ($app, $db) {

  require('processingclass.php');
  $foo = new FooClass();

});
```

This above is obviously an incomplete Slim example. But, how would I call a $db method from within $foo?

I have a bunch of routes and want to have access to the DB class from all the secondary classes used in the individual routes - w/o setting a global or loading/instantiating the DB class within each secondary class or route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% clear on the [Slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) structure or if there are built in methods to handle such a task in Slim, but would it not be best to pass it this way?

```
$foo = new FooClass($db);
```

And then in the `FooClass()` just have a call to set the `$db` in constructor? Something like this?

```
class FooClass {

  private $db = null;

  function __construct($db) {

    $this->db = $db;

  }

}
```

Again my POV is coming from generic PHP class & OOP knowledge. So unclear if there is a better way in Slim. If there is, would be welcome to understand more.

Comment: I'd even type-hint the constructor arg, eg `__construct(DataClass $db)`

Comment: Wow. Ok. Yeah...that would definitely work! Thanks Jake and Phil! :)

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way to do this is declare in the app container (index.php).
You already got the `$app` initiating Slim.
Get the container using `$container = $app->getContainer();`

After this you just simply do this:

```
$container['fooclass'] = function($container) {
    $fooClass = new FooClass(...)
    return $fooClass
}
```

Then you can use it everywhere doing

```
$this->fooclass
```